# Pandas Denormalization

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes I'd like to denormalize into one, e.g given:

```
>>> data1 = [['Akbar', 42], ['Akbar', 99], ['Jeff', 1]]
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ["who", "number"])
>>> data2 = [['Akbar', "SF"], ["Jeff", "NYC"]]
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ["who", "where"])
>>> df1
     who  number
0  Akbar      42
1  Akbar      99
2   Jeff       1
>>> df2
     who where
0  Akbar    SF
1   Jeff   NYC
>>>
```

I want to end up with

```
>>> df1
     who  number  where
0  Akbar      42     SF
1  Akbar      99     SF
2   Jeff       1    NYC
```

df1 has ~500k records and df2 has ~20k records so I'm looking for an efficient approach.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: `df1['where'] =df1['who'].map(dict(zip(df2['who'], df2['where'])))`

Comment: Use `df1.merge(df2)`.

Comment: Try the following

    df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'who')

or

    df1 = df1.merge(df2, on = 'who')

Comment: Or `df1['where'] = df1.map(df2.set_index('who')['where'])` this might be faster than merge ig.

Comment: Thanks @wwnde - I went with your suggestion which worked great.

Whoever closed it with the pointer to Merging 101 - appreciate it and I have bookmarked that to circle back to.